# Mount disk used by rook-ceph

Tags: linux, ceph

I'm running a Kubernetes cluster with 3 nodes, each having 2 hard drives, one with Linux installed on. Another that I didn't mount to let rook store data on it. I've seen on the documentation that rook won't accept any disk where NTFS is already installed on.

This is working well but I can't "see" my data. I mean I can't navigate to my second disk because it has not been mounted. `cd /dev/sdb/...` is not possible.

But I would like to have an eye on what is stored on that second disk. Is it possible to mount it in a way to not disturbing rook functionalities?

Comment: Your ceph cluster probably is deployed using bluestore which doesn't have a  usual filesystem to navigate in (which was possible on filestore). Bluestore works directly on the raw block device [https://ceph.io/community/new-luminous-bluestore/].

Comment: The link your provdided is dead :/
And isn't it a way to "visualize" data stored via Bluestore ? I like all the advantages of having a rook-ceph cluster but not being able to "view" the files is a bit annoying..

Comment: My bad: https://ceph.io/community/new-luminous-bluestore/
Well, there is an option to deploy filestore OSDs but that wouldn't be progress. I guess you'll have to live with it. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'l have to test it but your article is saying "If the OSD is stopped, you can “mount” the OSD data via FUSE with

    $ mkdir /mnt/foo
    $ ceph-objectstore-tool --op fuse --data-path /var/lib/ceph/osd/ceph-75 --mountpoint /mnt/foo".
So their might be a way to visualize data on a stopped OSD.

Comment: Yes, you can inspect offline OSDs but you won't be able to map that to any files you're looking for.